# static initialization order and concatenation of strings

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation, static-initialization

We have a rather large project that defines `static const std::string`s in several places to be used as parameter names; some of them need to be concatenated during static initialization:

foo.h:

```
struct Foo {
  static const std::string ParamSuffix;
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
const std::string Foo::ParamSuffix = ".suffix";
```

bar.h:

```
struct Bar {
  static const std::string ParamPrefix;
};
```

bar.cpp:

```
const std::string Bar::ParamPrefix = "prefix";
```

baz.h:

```
struct Baz {
    static const std::string ParamName;
};
```

baz.cpp:

```
const std::string Baz::ParamName = Bar::ParamPrefix + Foo::ParamSuffix;
```

The problem is obviously the "static initialization fiasco" as it is undefined in which order the `static const` members are initialized.

I dislike the usual solution, i.e. replace all these variables by functions, because

1. There's a lot of these variables, i.e. a lot of code changes
2. The concatenations require special functions, which makes the code base inconsistent and even more ugly

I currently cannot use C++11, which would make things easier with its `constexpr` feature (I think).

**The question is:** Is there any trick that would allow me to concatenate `static const std::string`s (or wrapper objects or whatever) to initialize another `static const std::string`?

Answer (score 3):

> The question is: Is there any trick that would allow me to concatenate static const std::strings (or wrapper objects or whatever) to initialize another static const std::string?

No trivial ones, other than the one you dislike: create functions for the static strings.

There are non-trivial alternatives though (e.g. replace all your hard-coded strings with a string container/string map and load the map on application start-up).

My recommendation though would be to go with static functions (the solution you rejected).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think that `std::string const` is in any way special? (hint: it is not) Even if you could use C++11's `constexpr` it wouldn't help because you can't make `std:string`s constant expressions (they may need to allocate memory which isn't a viable constant expression). You could deal with a string-like class used for `constexpr` that could be made to convert to `std::string` but I'm not sure if these could be concatenated to produce a new `constexpr`.

What you maybe able to do is to extract those strings you need to use as part of a concatenation and provide their value as macro. String literals (which have type `char const[N]` for a suitable `N`) can be concatenated by simply placing them next to each other:

```
// foo.h
#define FOO_PARAM_SUFFIX ".suffix"
struct Foo {
    static const std::string ParamSuffix;
};

// foo.cpp:
std::string const Foo::ParamSuffix(FOO_PARAM_SUFFIX);

// bar.h:
#define BAR_PARAM_SUFFIX "prefix"
struct Bar {
    static std::string const ParamPrefix;
};

// bar.cpp:
std::string const Bar::ParamPrefix(BAR_PARAM_SUFFIX);

// baz.h:
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
#define BAZ_PARAM_NAME BAR_PARAM_PREFIX FOO_PARAM_SUFFIX

struct Baz {
    static std::string const ParamName;
};

// baz.cpp:
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"
std::string const Baz::ParamName(BAR_PARAM_PREFIX FOO_PARAM_SUFFIX);
```

I would guess that `BAZ_PARAM_NAME` isn't used elsewhere in which case it also doesn't have to be defined: it is defined just to show it can be done. The initialization of `Bar::ParamName` assumes that `BAZ_PARAM_NAME` isn't defined.

Comment: Before using macros, I could still use `const char Foo::ParamSuffix[] = ".suffix"` etc and convert these to `std::string` before concatenation into `Baz::ParamName`, but I'd like a solution with consistent types everywhere or at least hidden ugliness.

Comment: @arne: you're missing the point... the preprocessor can place quoted strings one after another in the source code, then the compiler concatenates them to form a single new string literal (i.e. an ASCIIZ C-style string "constant").  You can't do anything with `std::string`s at compile time for the reasons Dietmar mentions in his answer.

Comment: @arne: `const char x[] = "...";` can't be concatenated. I'm also not sure if they would be initialized early enough (i.e., prior to dynamic initialization or as part of dynamic initialization). These may very well have the same problem as the `std::string` objects.

Comment: @Dietmar: the `const char x[]` solution worked when we tried it -- the string's contents were put verbatim into the read-only section of the executable. Converting these to `std::string` (as I mentioned before) and concatenating those (as I also mentioned before) works quite well. It's still ugly though.

Comment: @TonyD I know that the preprocessor is able to do such things. I still find the solution ugly because of namespace pollution and what not.

Comment: @arne: of course - you're in an ugly situation and trying to avoid cleaning it up wholesale...

Answer (score 2):

When the text is not dependent on another variable, you might consider changing the type from `const std::string` to a `const char` array ala `const char param_prefix[] = "prefix";` -  there may well be less forced change to client usage, but that could hide new temporary `std::string`s having to be (or unintentionally being) created each time they're used.

Check your system, but you can almost certainly safely use those `const char` variables in the construction of other `std::string` constants - but you're out of luck for necessarily-`std::string` dependencies on other `std::string`s.

If it's too hard to untangle the existing values into can-be-`const`-`char` and `std::string`s that only depend on `const`-`char`s, or that just doesn't cover enough of your cases, then wholesale modifications to every constant are worth pursuing.

The appeal of wrappers is that you can keep the type and semantics of usage the same.  To do that, you'll need to replace all these runtime-initialised strings with your own type that coordinates two central lists: - initialised objects, and waiting objects.  An observer pattern is appropriate, or you could e.g. register a list of callbacks and complete initialisation by looping in `main()` calling them until they all indicate success: if at least some of the object initialisation is known to be static then that could allow one object to test another's initialisation status, which would avoid having to have constructors register their completion.

If it's possible with the help of smarter source code modifying tools (e.g. awk) - it may be better to simply change the constants to be cleanly returned by functions.